# Script to figure out the difference in disk space

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a Linux command that shows the output of disk usage

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       2.8T  1.1T  1.7T  39% /data/disk2
/dev/sdc1       2.8T  1.1T  1.7T  41% /data/disk3
/dev/sdd1       2.8T  1.1T  1.7T  40% /data/disk4
```

I need help with continue this in a script (Python or Bash) to let me know if the disks are more than 5% different of each other. If they are over 5% imbalanced, I will write code to email the results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm very new to linux, the only thing I could think off is creating a file and use diff command on new generated files. Im sure there are many easier ways

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
import re

s = """
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       2.8T  1.1T  1.7T  39% /data/disk2
/dev/sdc1       2.8T  1.1T  1.7T  41% /data/disk3
/dev/sdd1       2.8T  1.1T  1.7T  40% /data/disk4
"""

regex = re.compile(r'\d{1,2}%')

result = [int(a[:-1]) for a in regex.findall(s)]
# [39, 41, 40]
```

If you want to compare them at the end...

```
if max(result) - min(result) > 5:
    print("Imbalanced!")
else:
    print("Balanced!")
```

Of course, you can call os-level functions and get their output like this:

```
command_output = subprocess.check_output(['df', '-h']).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: result = [int(a[:-1]) for a in regex.findall(p)]
                   TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @user3508766 What is `p`?

Comment: p = Popen(["ansible","dr-data","-m","shell","-a","df -h /data/disk*"], 
stdin=PIPE)

Comment: @user3508766 That is your issue...the result from `Popen()` is not a string...try what I posted: `subprocess.check_output()`.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `awk`, too:

```
df | awk '\
    BEGIN { \
        max=0; \
        min=2000; \
    } \
    NR>1 { \
      pf = $5; \
      sub( /\%/, "", pf ); \
      pf = pf + 0; \
      if ( pf > max ) max = pf; \
      if ( pf < min ) min = pf; \
    } \
    END { \
      diff = ( max - min ); \
      print diff \
    }'
```

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1{ a[NR-1]=substr($5,1,length($5)-1) }
        END{ asort(a); print ((a[length(a)]-a[1]) > 5? "Not good!" : "Good!") }'
```

The output (for your input):

```
Good!
```

Comment: is this supposed to be without single quotes? df -h | awk NR>1{ a[NR-1]=substr($5,1,length($5)-1) }
        END{ asort(a); print ((a[length(a)]-a[1]) > 5? "Not good!" : "Good!") }

Comment: @user3508766, what are you saying?